# Using custom icons for iSwiper iDangerous pagination

Tags: jquery, css, pagination

I am trying to use custom icons for pagination with iSwiper. I have managed to add the icons to the pagination using the following code (initiated after the swiper is created)

```
var countPagination = 0;
     $(".swiper-pagination-switch").each(function() {
            if (countPagination == 1) {
                $(this).html("<i class='fa fa-check iconFooter'></i>");            
            } else if (countPagination == 2) {                                
              $(this).html("<i class='fa fa-check iconFooter'></i>");
            } else if (countPagination == 3) {
               $(this).html("<i class='fa fa-check iconFooter'></i>");
            } else if (countPagination == 4) {
                $(this).html("<i class='fa fa-check iconFooter'></i>");
            } else if (countPagination == 5) {
                 $(this).html("<i class='fa fa-check iconFooter'></i>"); 

            }
                        countPagination++;


                    });
```

I am using font-awesome icons and they all appear perfectly. The problem is that when I try to click the pagination exactly where the icon is, it doesn't detect the click. It seems like a z-index issue so I adjusted the css to set the z-index for the icons as z-index:0; and the pagination as z-index:5 but it doesn't seem to help.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use default [pagination function](http://www.idangero.us/swiper/api/):

```
    mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        initialSlide: 1,
        pagination: ".pagination",
        paginationClickable: true,
        paginationBulletRender: function (index, className) {
            return '<span class="' + className + ' page' + index + '">page number ' + (index + 1) + ' or and any other text here</span>';
        }
    });
```

then you can easy manage styles for each pagination button:

```
.pagination .page1 {background:url(...) no-repeat; width:50px; height:50px;} 
.pagination .page2 {background:url(...)}
```

Comment: Yea I saw that from their API but I don't want to use numbers and the font awesome icons are all classes using the <I></I>

Comment: ok, then: `return '<i class="' + className + ' page' + index + '"></i>'`